# How do i force spring-boot to use jaxb?

Tags: spring-boot, jaxb, jackson

We have some xml that uses capitol letters for all fields.  Spring boot automatically uses jackson which does not work well with this.  I have the xml "jaxb"d into java objects that tell it to use the capitol letters.  However spring always seems to use Jackson.

Anyway to force it to use Jaxb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) a list of commonly used in spring-boot properties for your *application.properties* file. You probably need:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=UPPER_CAMEL_CASE
```

[Here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/PropertyNamingStrategy.html) are the available naming strategies for Jackson.

If you insist on Jaxb I believe it will be used by spring boot unless you include `jackson-dataformat-xml` in your classpath (may have to exclude it).